# Connecting to non geodatabase MS Access database using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to connect to an MS Access database from a program I have written in VB.Net with ArcObjects 10.0.  My MS Access database is not a personal geodatabase so apparently I have to connect to Access using an OLEDBWorkspaceFactory.

```
Dim propset As IPropertySet2 = New PropertySet
propset.SetProperty("CONNECTIONSTRING", "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & txtbox1.Text & ";User Id=admin;Password=;")

Dim oleWorkspace As IWorkspaceFactory2 = New OLEDBWorkspaceFactory
Dim m_workspace As IWorkspace2

If oleWorkspace IsNot Nothing Then m_workspace = oleWorkspace.Open(propset, 0)
```

The above code works except for one minor detail.  When I call `oleWorkspace.Open(propset, 0)` I get the ArcGIS Database Connection dialogue asking what driver to use and for connection information (which I have already provided in my propertyset).

Is there a way to avoid this dialogue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [AccessWorkspaceFactory](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001m00000001000000) co-class even though it's not a personal geodatabase. You could also use [ADO.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET). I am not sure why your code isn't working but I do know that working with property sets is an exercise in frustration.

Comment: I originally did it with the AccessWorkspaceFactory, but any joins I try to create (using memoryrelationshipclass) do not work because my tables do not have objectid's.

Answer (score 0):

Is the username actually 'admin' and password blank?

Try removing those parameters from your property set. I usually don't include them if the db is not password protected. Also verify that your txtbox1.Text string is what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ADO.NET. If you are just trying to access information from a normal database, use the methods that .NET has packaged within their framework.

```
Dim connectionString As String
    Dim cnn As OleDbConnection
    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourdatabasename.mdb;"
    cnn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        MsgBox("Yeah, that's cool. You opened me. Kudos.")
        cnn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("That's right, crawl back into the hole you came from. Fail.")
    End Try
```